# connecting my printer to my windows 8 tablet to print wireless

Tags: wireless-networking

My printer is a H P 3520 all in one it is already connected up right to print normally. But the wireless part does not work on my windows 8 tablet.

Comment: What have you tried to do already, is wireless printing definitely enabled on the printer?

Comment: What tablet do you have.  The simplest way is to install the HP software to handle the configuration of the printer to pc communication.